# How to load a page from a page without modifying the url in JSP?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a web application which is secured by login. If a user's session has expired how do I display an error page when the user attempts to load the secured page without causing the URL pathname to change? The reason why is because I don't want to reveal what extensions I am using. I know I could just specify an index page to a directory but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. Also I would like to avoid modifying any standard error code pages (ex: 403/404). Something that loads/redirects on page load would be nice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reveal your extensions you use a .htaccess with mod-rewrite.

You could do two things to make sure you hide them. First if a request comes to a page with a `.` character after the first `/` you redirect them to the same page but with the `.` and everything after it stripped off.

Secondly you mod rewrite your page so that a request to `https://mydomain.com/mypage` gets rewritten server side as `` `https://mydomain.com/mypage.extension ``